# range.cells.copy to range.cells.paste in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to copy a set on cells from the last filled column of a particular row to the next column . I am not getting any error but the values are not getting pasted.

my code :

Dim ed As Variant
      Dim ee As Variant

```
  ed = ActiveSheet.Cells(55, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  ee = ActiveSheet.Cells(55, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ed, 55), ActiveSheet.Cells(ed, 68)).Copy ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ee, 55), ActiveSheet.Cells(ee, 68))
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've transposed row and column in your copy statement.

Instead of `ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ed, 55), ActiveSheet.Cells(ed, 68)).Copy ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ee, 55), ActiveSheet.Cells(ee, 68))` try:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(55,ed), ActiveSheet.Cells(68, ed)).Copy ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(55, ee), ActiveSheet.Cells(68, ee))
```

But there are a number of better ways to achieve this range copy.

Comment: Hi Dave , Thanks this works.. What would be a more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: You can actually set a range to be another range e.g. `ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(55, ee), ActiveSheet.Cells(68, ee)) = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(55,ed), ActiveSheet.Cells(68, ed)).Value` - it's also recommended not to use `ActiveSheet` in a number of cases in case the user switches the sheet, but instead set a reference to a sheet `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")` and then refer to `ws` instead of `ActiveSheet`. At the very least you'll type a lot less ;)